Are $I(n)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^{-2/3}(1-y)^{-2/3}}{1-xy}\left(\frac{x y(1-x)(1-y)}{1-xy}\right)^{n}$ all rationally dependent?
Consider a sequence of integrals
$$
I(n)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^{-2/3}(1-y)^{-2/3}}{1-xy}\left(\frac{x y(1-x)(1-y)}{1-xy}\right)^{n}dxdy
$$
There exists an algorithm, called Multivariable Almkvist-Zeilberger algorithm, or MAZ, for short, that is designed to find recurrences in integral sequences just like $I(n)$.
An application of MAZ to $I(n)$ reveals that
$$I(n+2)=R_1(n)\cdot I(n+1)+R_2(n) \cdot I(n)$$
where $R_1(n)$ and $R_2(n)$ are known rational functions. That means that all such integrals are rationally dependent with $I(1)$ and $I(0)$. But I think that $I(1)$ and $I(0)$ might also be rationally dependent, that is, for some integers $a,b$, and $c$
$$aI(1)+bI(0) = c$$
That would imply that all such integrals are in a sense defined by $I(0)$. So the question is, are the two integrals
$$\begin{align}
I(0) =& \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^{-2/3}(1-y)^{-2/3}}{1-xy}dxdy\\
I(1) =& \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^{1/3}(1-y)^{1/3}\cdot y(1-x)}{(1-xy)^2}dxdy
\end{align}$$
rationally related?
Addendum. The problem could also be recast in the language of generalized hypergeometric function ${}_3F_2$. In fact
$${}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}1+n, ~~~ 1+n, ~~~ \frac13+n\\\frac43+2n,
~~~\frac43+2n\end{matrix};1\right)$$
is rationally dependent with $I(n)$ via the Euler integral transformation. The question then could be generalized to state the following: consider a real parameter $\alpha>0$, are the two hypergeometric series
$$\begin{align}
{}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}1, ~~~ 1, ~~~ \alpha\\\ 1+\alpha,
~~~1+\alpha\end{matrix};1\right)\\
{}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}2, ~~~ 2, ~~~ 1+\alpha\\\ 3+\alpha,
~~~3+\alpha\end{matrix};1\right)\\
\end{align}$$
linearly dependent?

$$\begin{aligned}
(1 + \alpha)^2 (2 + \alpha)^2 (1 + \alpha + \alpha^2) \cdot
{}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}1,  1, \alpha\\ 1+\alpha,
1+\alpha\end{matrix};1\right)\

\alpha^2  \cdot {}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}2,  2,  1+\alpha\\ 3+\alpha,
3+\alpha\end{matrix};1\right)\
= (1 + \alpha)^2 (2 + \alpha)^2 (2 + 2 \alpha + \alpha^2)
\end{aligned}$$


@user1386629. This is amazing! How did you derive this?

@Nikitan Have you tried using contiguous relations to connect the two hypergeometric functions?

@DavidH, I have thought about it, but because the bottom parameters get incremented by two, I couldn't get anything nice. I am still not very hypergeometric-savvy, so I might have missed something.

One way prove such identities is as specializations with $z=1$ of more complicated identities with other hypergeometric functions that vanish at $z=1$. A similar example is Theorem 2 of Nesterenko in this paper: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1134/S0081543816010107.pdf. It seemed a little tedious to try to work out the details which is why I just left a comment.

But finding such identities is easy. Explicitly I numerically computed the values for $\alpha = 1/3$ to $1000$ decimal places and then used LLL. Then I computed the values for $\alpha = 1/n$ for $n=3,\ldots,11$, used LLL again, then interpolated in $\alpha$.

@user1386629, you seem to have an amazing framework of knowledge about hypergeometric functions! How did you acquire it? I've learned about them fairly recently and it seems I still don't know about many important concepts!
That Yuri Nesterenko article is actually the reason I thought about this question in the first place! But I thought the theorems there are very specialized and it had not occured to me that there is a bigger idea behind theorem 2.

The identity mentioned by @user1386629 is actually mechanical to verify once it has been written down. The two $_3F_2$ each satisfies a 2nd order recurrence in $\alpha$, LHS satisfies at most a 4th order recurrence, one checks the polynomial in RHS also satisfies this 4th order recurrence. Then one checks the identity for $\alpha = 0,1,2$, here the two $_3F_2$ can be computed via partial fraction. Thus the purported identity holds for $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$. It holds for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ by Carlson's theorem.

OP might be familiar to above technique since MAZ algorithm was mentioned. FYI, one actually has $${}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}1,  1, \alpha\\ 1+\alpha,  1+\alpha\end{matrix};1\right) = \frac{1}{2} a^2 \left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$ in terms of polygamma function.

@pisco's right, and in particular
$$2 I(0) = 2 \iint_{[0,1]^2} \frac{x^{-2/3} (1-y)^{-2/3}}{1 - x y} dxdy = 8 \zeta(2) + 27 L(2,\chi_{-3})= 34.2546376\ldots$$
is irrational, although proving that fact takes a little work.

@user1386629 I am very curious for a reference that proves this number is irrational.

@user1386629, I would have imagined that proving irrationality for $I(0)$ would be insurmountably difficult! Wadim Zudilin studied a similar integral in search of a way to prove the irrationality of Catalan's constant but was ultimately unsuccessful.

It follows from Theorem A of this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2408.15403), in particular the "More generally..."

@user1386629, the formula
$${}3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}1,  1, 1/3\\ 4/3,  4/3\end{matrix};1\right) = \frac{4}{9} \zeta(2)+\frac{3}{2} L(2,\chi{-3})$$
seems very interesting! How can one find something like this? I presume the idea behind it isn't something that works for all $\alpha = \frac{1}{n}, n\in \mathbb{Z}$?

There is literally a formula given by @pisco above which gives such an evaluation since the values of the corresponding polygamma function are linear multiples of Dirichlet $L$-values $L(s,\chi)$ at $s=2$ when $\chi$ has order dividing $2n$ if $\alpha = 1/n$.

Oh! That's so cool! Thank you!
